# PYSimpleGui event in combination with keyboard.is_pressed('key') working every time, except first time after program start

Tags: python, keyboard-events, pysimplegui

PYSimpleGui event in combination with keyboard.is_pressed('key') working every time, except first time after program start. So the first click never works, but every other click works.

Hardcoding my button event is not an option, I have to check for several keys, the program is pretty complex already. File explorer.
Try it yourself....can't make it work the first time, without an artificial mouse-click at program start.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import keyboard
from time import sleep

layout = [
    [
        sg.Button('', enable_events=True, key=(1, 1))
    ]
        ]

window = sg.Window('Image Browser', layout,
                   return_keyboard_events=False, finalize=True, auto_size_buttons=False, use_default_focus=True,
                   resizable=True, size=(100, 100))

while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=0)

    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

    if type(event) is tuple and keyboard.is_pressed('shift'):
        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")

    sleep(0.01)
```

Hello there. I have tried different window arguments,..like focus, return_keyboard_events etc.
Also tried different timeouts, and putting the is_pressed down a line,... like

```
if type(event) is tuple:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('shift'):
        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
```

Also which button does not matter.
What helps is sending an artificial mouse-click to that button, when the program starts.
Seems a bit hacky..lol.
It would not make a good impression if I hijack the mouse at program start, and put it back where it was...lol.
User like: "What just happened??"...lol
I am sure I miss something here.

Comment: @Jason Yang.
Well you are a PySimpleGui expert, you are one of the people I was hoping to give me some insight.
Well the question is in the title.
PYSimpleGui event in combination with keyboard.is_pressed('key') working every time, except first time after program start. So the first click never works, but every other click works. Try it out!! 
`print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")` never gets triggered the first time I click the button,...but every time afterwards.
No matter what I change or try, see post,,,,always the same behavior.

Comment: @JasonYang Still don't get why you don't understand. Does the code work on your system for the FIRST click? It just doesn't register the FIRST click for me.

Comment: Don't finalize window

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution!!
I just have to put ANY arbitrary keyboard read in, after the program starts.

It can be `keyboard.get_hotkey_name()` or `keyboard.is_pressed('shift')` or `keyboard.is_pressed('a')`

Full solution:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import keyboard
from time import sleep

keyboard.get_hotkey_name() # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

layout = [
    [
        sg.Button('', enable_events=True, key=(1, 1))
    ]
        ]

window = sg.Window('Image Browser', layout,
                   return_keyboard_events=False, finalize=True, auto_size_buttons=False, use_default_focus=True,
                   resizable=True, size=(100, 100))

while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=0)

    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

    if type(event) is tuple and keyboard.is_pressed('shift'):
        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")

    sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind event to keypress, for example:

```
# 'esc' event
window.bind("<Escape>", "-ESCAPE-")
```